# How to delete the collection data on mongodb while doing unit testing with mocha and chai

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, chai

I am stuck one issue where I am unit testing of API's with mongodb. I am using Mocha and Chai for unit testing, however I am facing issue that when I am test second case I need to empty the mongodb collection so new data will come and test automatically, but I could not find anything how to delete the collection every time before unit test code run.

Please see below my unit test code

test.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
let mongoose = require("mongoose");
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const request = require('supertest');

const app = require('../../../app.js');
const conn = require('../../../db/index.js');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
describe('notes', () => {
  beforeEach((done) => { //Before each test we empty the database
      Book.remove({}, (err) => { 
         done();           
      });        
  });
});


describe('GET /notes', () => {
  before((done) => {
    conn.connect()
      .then(() => done())
      .catch((err) => done(err));
  })

  after((done) => {
    conn.close()
      .then(() => done())
      .catch((err) => done(err));
  })

  it('OK, getting notes has no notes', (done) => {
    request(app).get('/notes')
      .then((res) => {
        const body = res.body;
        expect(body.length).to.equal(0); // getting error here as collection have data
        // res.should.have.status(200);

        done();
      })
      .catch((err) => done(err));
  });
```

> app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const Note = require('./db/models/note.js').Note;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/notes', (req, res) => {
  Note.find()
    .then((notes) => res.status(200).send(notes))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).send(err));
});

app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  const note = new Note({
    name: body.name,
    text: body.text
  });
  note.save(note)
    .then((note) => res.status(201).send(note))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).send(err));
});

module.exports = app;
```

please suggest me how can I delete the mongodb collection before the unit test?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're doing unit tests you should mock the database interaction. If you're looking to test the integration between the application code and database you'd probably want to explore integration tests or end-to-end tests using other tooling.

Comment: Hi @ Nic Thanks for advise, I have check with mock mongodb and lucky I have found it also it working fine for me now